# not able to deploy portlet war in liferay

Tags: java, ant, liferay, liferay-6

I am tying to place war file into tomcat's deploy folder. It is not getting deployed. When I try to deploy it using install plugins from control panel, I am getting error like.

```
eDeployer:971] Not updating SamplePorject because version 6.2.1 is newer than version 6.2.0.1
```

I noticed that, I am using Liferay 6.2 GA1 sdk and try to deploy in folder. Later on I changed my SDK to Liferay 6.2 GA2. but Still I am getting the error.

Do I need to change the run time environment as well.

my generated war is having version 6.2.0.1.

Comment: Are you generating war file against same version liferay-plugin-sdk?

Comment: Hi Pankaj, I just got portlet code. I don't know the version of SDK. whereas   both liferay-plugin-package.properties have the same properties and same values.

Answer (score 3):

Add `liferay-versions=6.2.0+` in `.../WEB-INF/liferay-plugin-package.properties` file.

Answer (score 2):

Liferay appears to store its own version in the RELEASE_ table in the database (BUILDNUMBER column) and compare artifacts that you try to deploy against that version.  I ran into a similar error trying to deploy a .lar file.  I was able to work around it  - you can try to update the database, or find the manifest or other entries in your artifact that have 6.2.1, but ultimately that will end in tears and you probably are best off updating your runtime, unless the SDK provides some way to target previous versions at build time.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but maybe it still helps anyone.

The error you are getting is at AutoDeploy process. In that process, Liferay takes your war and injects some files in it. Finally the generated war goes to your auto deploy destination dir (auto.deploy.dest.dir).

By default this dest dir is the same as your hot deploy dir, and in your case there is already one war for the same plugin in that folder, as you tried the autodeploy first. That's why you're getting versioning conflicts.

You should remove the war from autodeploy folder before trying to deploy it from Control Panel. And then look for the actual reason of your hot deploy not working.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the portlet with the higher version.Log in as admin then go to:

1. Control Panel > Manage Apps
2. Find portlet with higher version
3. Click on the Actions button then select uninstall
4. Then click Control Panel > Install
5. Install portlet with the lower version